# Why does invariance commute with partial derivative?

Tags: string-theory, symmetry, differentiation, supergravity, invariants

This question applies more generally to actions, but I am going to ask it for a specific example.

I am getting confused when considering the invariance of the superstring action under Weyl transformations as detailed in the comments to this question

https://www.physicsoverflow.org/19812/proof-that-the-superstring-action-is-weyl-invariant

I'm just confused as to why we can commute the invariance with the derivative:
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\Lambda} \partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu} =  \partial_{\alpha} \delta_{\Lambda}X^{\mu} \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Especially when we have to take into account this $\alpha$ symbol for the curved gamma matrices by writing 
$$\rho^{\alpha}= \rho^a e^{\alpha}_a,$$
where $e^{\alpha}_a$ is the zweibein, and so 
$$\delta_{\Lambda} \rho^{\alpha} = \rho^a \delta_{\Lambda}.$$
I guess what I'm asking is why don't we have to write 
$$\partial_{\alpha} = \partial_a e^a_{\alpha},$$
in which case we wouldn't have $(1)$ hold?